# In addition to the structure realized in Task 1, a function will be created

Tags: oracle, plsql

TASK 1 :
Step 1: First; The curexample_test table was created with the following script.

```
create table curexample_test (id number, x number, y number, result number, process_flag varchar2(1), error_message varchar2(400))

insert into curexample_test
select 1, 20,4,null,null,null from dual
union
select 2, 15,3,null,null,null from dual
union
select 3, 36,9,null,null,null from dual
union
select 4, 7,0,null,null,null from dual
union
select 5, 105,15,null,null,null from dual

select * from curexample_test
```

Step 2: What to do;

- Printing x/y in the result field in the curexample_test table with
  a procedure or function,
- If x/y is written successfully, write 'S'    in the process_flag
  field in the table, and 'E' in the process_flag    field if
  unsuccessful,
- In unsuccessful cases, the error message    should be printed in the
  error_message field in the table.
  Step 3:    Sample output is given
  below.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u2ch.png)

TASK 1 Answer :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION divider (n1 IN NUMBER, n2 IN NUMBER)
       RETURN NUMBER
    IS
       PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  
       v_result  NUMBER;
    BEGIN
       IF n2 = 0
       THEN
        v_result := NULL;

         UPDATE curexample_test SET result = v_result, process_flag = 'E'
                 WHERE     x = n1 AND y = n2     
                 
         UPDATE curexample_test SET  error_message ='ora-01476 divisor is equal to zero'
                 WHERE    process_flag = 'E';
               
     ELSE
         v_result := n1 / n2;
 
         UPDATE curexample_test
           SET result = v_result, process_flag = 'S'
                 WHERE     x = n1  AND y = n2;
                 
      END IF;

     COMMIT;
      RETURN v_result;
  END;
  select id,x,y , divider(x,y) as result,process_flag,error_message from curexample_test;
```

TASK 2:

Step 1:
In addition to the structure realized in Task 1, a function will be created. The function will take 4 parameters and return 1 value. After filling the 2 variables sent to it, it will output it.

Step 2: Example function structure is given in the screenshot below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLQSs.png)

Comment: A function can return only 1 result. If you want too many values to return from it, You must have a procedure instead of a function.

Comment: At SO the community will help you with your problems but **it is not a code writing service**. Please take a few minutes to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. Specifically what have you tried and what were the actual results. Also provide sample data as text - **no images** and the expected result of that data.